# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 Rotating PNG is skewed

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation, opengl-es-2.0

I try to make some "simple" tests.
I have encountered many difficulties but I don't find the solution for one of them.

My test is:

1. Drawing a rotating square (made with 2 triangles)
2. Drawing a rotating texture (png loaded file)

The problem is that the drawn png is skewed while rotating, not the square.

[image: 0 degree]

[image: 90 degrees]

As you can see, the squre keeps the same dimensions through the rotation while the scale is "resized", like if I wanted it to always fit into the screen.

Below, you can find some of my code:

The projection matrix that I used

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    this.screenWidth = width;
    this.screenHeight = height;
    float ratio = (float) width / height;

    // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
    // in the onDrawFrame() method
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
}
```

The view matrix and rotation matrix

```
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

        // Rotation matrix
        float[] scratch = new float[16];
        // Same rotation matrix except the angle is the opposite
        // Because of the way the PNG is loaded ?
        float[] scratch_ = new float[16];

        // Redraw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Set the camera position (View matrix)
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        // Calculate the projection and view transformation
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

        // Create a rotation transformation for the triangle
        float angle = 90;
        Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, angle, 0, 0, 1.0f);
        Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix_, 0, -angle, 0, 0, 1.0f);

        // Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
        // Note that the mMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
        // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch_, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix_, 0);

        //draw square and scale
        draw(scratch, scratch_)
    }
```

The coordinates of my elements

```
    float squareCoords[] = {
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
            0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right

    float scaleCoords[] = {
            -0.2f,  1.5f,   // top left
            -0.2f, -0.5f,   // bottom left
            0.2f, -0.5f,   // bottom right
            0.2f,  1.5f}; // top right
```

Finally, you can find below my "Image" class that I use to draw the PNG

```
public class Image {
    //Reference to Activity Context
    private final Context mActivityContext;

    //Added for Textures
    private final FloatBuffer mCubeTextureCoordinates;
    private int mTextureUniformHandle;
    private int mTextureCoordinateHandle;
    private final int mTextureCoordinateDataSize = 2;
    private int mTextureDataHandle;


    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate;" +
                    "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +
                    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_Position = vPosition * uMVPMatrix;" +
                    //Test
                    "v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;" +
                    //End Test
                    "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
                    "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;" +
                    "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate);" +
                    "}";

    private final int shaderProgram;
    private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private final ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 2;

    private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; //Order to draw vertices
    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; //Bytes per vertex

    public Image(final Context activityContext, float[] coords)
    {
        mActivityContext = activityContext;

        //Initialize Vertex Byte Buffer for Shape Coordinates / # of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(coords.length * 4);
        //Use the Device's Native Byte Order
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        //Create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        //Add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
        vertexBuffer.put(coords);
        //Set the Buffer to Read the first coordinate
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // U, V coordinates
        final float[] cubeTextureCoordinateData =
                {
                        0.0f,  0.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f,  0.0f
                };

        mCubeTextureCoordinates = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(cubeTextureCoordinateData.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        mCubeTextureCoordinates.put(cubeTextureCoordinateData).position(0);

        //Initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(coords.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader = PfdRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = PfdRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        shaderProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);

        //Texture Code
        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "a_TexCoordinate");

        GLES20.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

        //Load the texture
        // Retrieve our image from resources.
        int id = mActivityContext.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/coeur_hsi", "drawable",
                mActivityContext.getPackageName());
        Log.d("Id of coeur_hsi is: ", Integer.toString(id));
        mTextureDataHandle = loadTexture(mActivityContext, id);
    }

    public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix)
    {
        //Add program to OpenGL ES Environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        //Get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vPosition");

        //Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        //Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        //Set Texture Handles and bind Texture
        mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "u_Texture");
        mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_TexCoordinate");

        //Set the active texture unit to texture unit 0.
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);

        //Bind the texture to this unit.
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle);

        //Tell the texture uniform sampler to use this texture in the shader by binding to texture unit 0.
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);

        //Pass in the texture coordinate information
        mCubeTextureCoordinates.position(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, mTextureCoordinateDataSize,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mCubeTextureCoordinates);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);

        //Get Handle to Shape's Transformation Matrix
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

        //Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

        //Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

        //Disable Vertex Array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }

    public static int loadTexture(final Context context, final int resourceId)
    {
        final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

        if (textureHandle[0] != 0)
        {
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inScaled = false;   // No pre-scaling

            // Read in the resource
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, options);

            // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

            // Set filtering
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

            // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

            // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
            bitmap.recycle();
        }

        if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
        }

        return textureHandle[0];
    }
}
```

My guess is that the error comes from the projection matrix but I can't figure out what the problem exactly is.
Could you tell me why my PNG image is skewed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like you miscalculated your gl_Position.

> "  gl_Position = vPosition * uMVPMatrix;"

When you look at Matrix multiplication, you gotta know that when multiplying two matrices (a Vertex is also a 1x4 Matrix) you multiply every row of the first matrix, with every columns of the second matrix. 
This only works if the matrices are "compatible". This means that the first matrix has to have the exact same amount of columns as the 2nd matrix has rows. E.g. you can multiply a 3x2 matrix with a 2x3 Matrix, but you couldn't multiply a 2x3 matrix with a 3x2 matrix.

Therefore Order is very important!

Try calculating it as

```
gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
```

Wiki has a good page on Matrix multiplication.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: Many thanks for your brief but very clear answer. You solved my problems!

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm going to edit my post with more detail for anyone with similar problems.